# Is there a surjective function such as $f:2^\Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb N$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

This seems like a pretty simple question but nothing helpful came to my mind.
Is there a surjective function such as:

$f:2^\Bbb N \rightarrow \Bbb N$

Comment: Map every subset that has $n$ as its smallest element to $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, simply for cardinality reasons there will be many such maps.

A concrete example: the function $f$ defined by taking $\alpha \in 2^{\mathbb N}$ to the first $n$ such that $\alpha(n) = 1$. This is surjective by considering $\alpha_n$ which is $1$ at $n$ and $0$ everywhere else.